Type 'ElementTypes' is not assignable to type 'ElementTypes.word'
i recently have learnt typescript, i encountered an error that i think i should write type narrower for it or something like that.
here's the code i wrote:
enum ElementTypes {
  h1 = 'H1',
  word = "WORD"
}

type DefaultElementType<T> = {
  children: string[];
  id: number | string;
  type: T;
};

type H1Element = DefaultElementType<ElementTypes.h1>;
type WordElement = DefaultElementType<ElementTypes.word> & {
  value: string;
}

type CustomElement =
  | H1Element
  | WordElement

const insertNode = (element: CustomElement) => {
  // do sth here, not important
}

const addInsertNode = ({type, id}: {type: ElementTypes, id: number | string}) => {
  insertNode({type, id, children:[], ...(type === ElementTypes.word ? {value: 'some value'}: {})})
}


and here's the error it gives:
Argument of type '{ value?: string | undefined; type: ElementTypes; id: string | number; children: never[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElement'.
  Type '{ value?: string | undefined; type: ElementTypes; id: string | number; children: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'WordElement'.
    Type '{ value?: string | undefined; type: ElementTypes; id: string | number; children: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'DefaultElementType<ElementTypes.word>'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'ElementTypes' is not assignable to type 'ElementTypes.word'.

I've tried writing Discriminated Unions but it didn't help.
here's a playground of the error.
I would appreciate any help.

The type property of element is ElementTypes but you need it to be ElementTypes.h1 for this to compile. You can get that to happen a number of ways, such as using a const assertion as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz well it solves the playground problem, but the playground is the simplified of my problem. In The main problem, element is an parameter and i can't set it as const. I can't provide you with an playground because it depends on dependencies.

If you can't provide a [mre] then how do you expect us to help you? I'm happy to suggest something else but the onus is on you to provide an example that motivates it. Make a different [mre] without the dependencies you're worried about. Otherwise this question might be closed as lacking debugging details.

@jcalz here's the closest i could get to the problem: playground

• Please [edit] the question to include the [mre] as plaintext. • Now your code is unsafe and the error is warning you about it. Look at this playground link. If a WordElement requires a value then { type, id, children: [] } cannot possibly be a WordElement. How you fix that is up to you; perhaps you can write some conditional code inside addInsertNode()? Or just add a value to the object literal regardless of type? But this is starting to be out of scope for the question as asked. Does that fully address the question now or am I still missing something?

@jcalz thanks for your help. I found the problem. I was using inline checks for value field but somehow typescript throw error for that. the playground for the problem

Okay, now the issue looks like TS's inability to handle "correlated unions" as described in ms/TS#30581.  You could try to do the generic refactoring described in ms/TS#47109 which gives you the code at this playground link, but instead you might just want to admit that this is beyond TS's abilities and merely assert that you're doing the right thing as shown at this playground link. How should I proceed with an answer?

@jcalz To be honest, i believe the addInsertNode should be divided into two functions. One for adding WordElement and one for H1Element. But this playground would be an ideal answer for this question.

I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

TypeScript only analyzes each bit of code once. If some expression has multiple mentions of the same value, and that value is of a union type, the compiler cannot analyze the expression for each member of that union. Instead it analyzes it once, and each value of the union type is treated independently. If you have a value v of type X | Y, then the compiler will see, say, [v, v] as having type [X | Y, X | Y] (conceptually like [X, X] | [X, Y] | [Y, X] | [Y, Y]) and not [X, X] | [Y, Y].  TypeScript is unable to deal with correlated unions directly.  This is the subject of microsoft/TypeScript#30581.
Inside addInsertNode(), the expression
{
  type, id, children: [],
  ...(type === ElementTypes.word ? { value: 'some value' } : {})
}

has two mentions of type, which is of the union type ElementTypes. Therefore the full expression is of a type like { type: ElementTypes } & ({value: string} | {}), which loses the correlation between type and the spread object. So the compiler cannot verify that the value is assignable to CustomElement, and you get an error.

There are various ways to proceed here. You can always just assert that your code is correct. This is the easiest approach and keeps your runtime code as-is:
const addInsertNode = ({ type, id }: { type: ElementTypes, id: number | string }) => {
  insertNode({
    type, id, children: [],
    ...(type === ElementTypes.word ? { value: 'some value' } : {})
  } as CustomElement)
}

The compiler does not verify the safety of your code anymore, but it's quick and easy to do.

If you want the compiler to verify type safety, then you'll need to refactor in some way. One way to proceed is to keep the union types and write one expression per union member.  You'd use narrowing to distinguish between the types of type. Like this:
const addInsertNode = ({ type, id }: { type: ElementTypes, id: number | string }) => {
  insertNode(
    (type === ElementTypes.word) ?
      { type, id, children: [], value: 'some value' } :
      { type, id, children: [] }
  )
}

This is redundant; the {type, id, children: [] part of the expression is repeated. But it works because now the compiler can see the type as being unequivocally ElementTypes.word in the true branch and ElementTypes.h1 if the false branch. Each expression has its own well-defined type.

The other approach is to keep the single expression but try to represent things in terms of generics instead of unions.  This technique is described in detail in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. The trick is to write a basic key-value mapping type, and then represent all your operations in terms of that type, or generic indexes into that type, or generic indexes into mapped types over that type.
The basic type looks like this:
interface ExtraProps {
  [ElementTypes.h1]: {},
  [ElementTypes.word]: { value: string; }
}

And then you can rewrite CustomElement to be a distributive object type:
type CustomElement<K extends ElementTypes = ElementTypes> =
  { [P in K]: DefaultElementType<P> & ExtraProps[P] }[K]

It's generic, so CustomElement<ElementTypes.h1> is the new name for your H1Element, while CustomElement<ElementTypes.word> is the new name for your WordElement.  And CustomElement by itself defaults to CustomElement<ElementTypes>, which is equivalent to your original CustomElemen union:
// demo that it's the same
type CE = CustomElement
/* type CE = DefaultElementType<ElementTypes.h1> | (DefaultElementType<ElementTypes.word> & {
    value: string;
}) */

Now we need to make insertNode generic:
const insertNode = <K extends ElementTypes>(element: CustomElement<K>) => {
  // do sth here, not important
}

And finally addInsertNode() also needs to be generic:
const addInsertNode = <K extends ElementTypes>({ type, id }: { type: K, id: number | string }) => {
  insertNode({
    type, id, children: [],
    ...{ [ElementTypes.h1]: {}, [ElementTypes.word]: { value: "some value" } }[type]
  })
}

Note that I've replaced the ternary (type === ElementTypes.word ? { value: 'some value' } : {}) with the equivalent { [ElementTypes.h1]: {}, [ElementTypes.word]: { value: "some value" } }[type].  Instead of a conditional, it does an object lookup. That object lookup matches ExtraProps[K] exactly, which lets the compiler see both possibilities for type as a single operation.
This refactoring works, but might not be worth it for your use case. Sometimes it's easy just to assert and move on, or write some more redundant code to take advantage of narrowing. But it's at least possible to get the compiler to follow the logic this way.
Playground link to code
